# WHERE OR clause not functioning right

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to select categories with certain id's and the sql query is acting really weird, take a look:

```
  SELECT * FROM (`feeds`) WHERE  `cat_id` =1 OR 2 OR 3 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The result includes an item with the cat_id of 4, see this picture:

[image: see here]

I need this to work, the script does this: a user specify's a country, the script gets all categories with that country id, then the script has to select all feeds with those category ids. The final part is to grab posts with all the feed ids from the previous parts. This is like a news site, the feeds are rss feeds that get imported. ny help would be appreciated! I'm using codeigniter for this, by the way.

Comment: Change condition in query to `cat_id  IN (1, 2, 3) ` or else `cat_id = 1 OR cat_id = 2 OR cat_id = 3`

Comment: @air4x wow, that was the biggest noob mistake ever! I'm getting too used to activer record, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `feeds`
WHERE  `cat_id` in (1 ,2 , 3)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

you cannot give

```
`cat_id` =1 OR 2 OR 3
```

it should be either

```
`cat_id` =1 OR `cat_id` =2 OR `cat_id` =3
```

or

```
`cat_id` in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (`feeds`) WHERE  `cat_id` =1 
OR `cat_id` =2  OR `cat_id` =3  LIMIT 0 , 30
```